# JComboBox with 4 cols and 4 rows data[][] form

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, render, jcombobox

In my Java Swing app, I need to have a `JComboBox` with four columns and four rows.  Basically, it's a combo box to select color.  When the combo box is collapsed, the user can see the first row's four columns, and when it's expanded, the user can see sixteen colors in 4x4 form.

I am not sure how to design such a combo box layout.  I can use a renderer, but I'm not sure about how to implement it.  I can only see two possibilities:

Create a `JLabel` named "ColorLabel" that draws a circle and fills the color of the circle as specified in its constructor.

1. Create a panel "ColorRowPanel" and add four ColorLabels in it.  Create four objects of ColorRowPanel and set that as the model to the combo box.
2. Create a `JTable` of 4x4 and add ColorLabel in each cell.  Set the `JTable` as the model of the `JComboBox`.

Is any of this possible?  If so, in what object do I add my ColorRowPanels/JTable to set as the model?  And when a color is selected, I should be able to know which colorLabel or which row-col is selected to get the color selected by user.

**UPDATE** 
Thanks. As per your guidances, I started up.

1) Created a class **ColorButton** of type JToggleButton - just to create a shape for the button. Nothing more is implemented. Code taken from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/506289/GUI/java/custom-shaped-gui-components)

2) Created a class **ColorContainer** that extends AbstractColorChooserPanel. Created a Panel of 4 btns and added 4 such panels to the class. Also implemented ButtonGroup to each button of the panels. Designed as shown in [CrayonPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ColorChooserDemo2Project/src/components/CrayonPanel.java) - added my initComponents() in buildChooser(). Constructor is empty. Rest all abstract methods are empty as per now.

3) Added panel to JCC and using JDialog.createDialog could show the ColorContainer. It comes properly fine, just I don't want the Ok, Cancel, Reset btns. I didn't find any option in JCC class or on net to hide the buttons panel of JCC dlg.

4) To try the same with Panel, I made ColorContainer extend JPanel instead of AbsColorChooserPanel and show the ColorContainer in Popup and it shows perfectly well.

I can't get way for 2 things yet - 
1) **MAIN - I want results like this** :

[image: Results I need]

1st part shows when the dropdown is collapsed & 2nd when it is shown. You see the 1st panel is still visible regardless of drop down been shown or collapsed.

What I got till now is : I added a JLAbel and on mouseEnter event I show the popup.

**How do I achieve the results as I want to ?** Can't think of a way to implement this.

2) Is it possible to hide the btns of JColorChooser and get the results as I am expecting !!

Please guide me and help me.

Comment: Consider [*Creating a Custom Chooser Panel*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html#chooserpanel).

Comment: and then don't forget to add ListSelectionListener to JTable in BasicComboBoxPopup, otherwise you will (problably) lost event from selection

Comment: #trashgod, please check comment on Sergiy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use combobox here. Combobox is designed to have 1 element in each popup row.

You should create a Panel with 4 buttons for the selected row and additional button to open the popup with 12 another buttons. To create the popup see the class `javax.swing.Popup`.

Here is the step-by-step guide:

1. Create panel with 4 color toggle Buttons and the button to open the
   popup.
2. Create Panel with 12 another color buttons.
3. Add all color buttons to a ButtonGroup
4. Make trigger to open/close popup and add it to the button to open
   the popup
5. Make trigger to close the popup if one of the color buttons is
   switched and add it to all color buttons.

Comment: trashgod, your Creating a Custom Chooser Panel and using Popup of @Sergiy gave me my idea to start up. If I use custom JToggleButton in my CustomChooser, then I guess I should add 16 toggle btns in the CustomChooserPanel itself. Sergiy, if I add 4 Panels with 4 btns in each panel then how I will be able to set selected only 1 toggle among 4 panels.

Comment: Use `javax.swingButtonGroup` class. Simply add all your buttons to the group and if one of the buttons get selected, all other buttons will be deselected

Comment: Pls chk the Updated part of the Question. Thanks

Comment: My answer is now up-to-date

Comment: Oh Thanks dear. Works great. Only 1 thing am not able to set - On mouseEnter on btn I show the popup. I want to hide it, if mouse is out of ColorContainer, btn, &/or btnsPanel. So, if the mouse is out of these 3 components then hide it. Rest on btn selected, it gets hidden perfectly. How to write the if clause for mouse out/Exit event of these 3 components ??

Comment: Pls check my comment and if Possible kindly help me with it. Thanks